# Upgrade Sitecore 7.2 SQL Analytics Database to Sitecore 9.0

Tags: migration

I have migrate one site from 7.2 to 9.0 and it is successfully done.

How i can migrate Analytics Database in to new version and in which database?

All data should display as it is in new version as well.

Please provide steps.

Comment: I do not think it is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sitecore (along with DMS Data) should be upgraded together.  While the Express Migration Tool looks appetizing, it does not upgrade DMS data.

The important guide for Sitecore Analytics is the xDB Upgrade Guide found for each version. The prerequisites of each guide highlight the upgrade Path.

From Sitecore 7.2, there are a few hoops you have to go through to get to Sitecore 9.

### Upgrade to Sitecore 7.5 rev. 141003

Following the [xDB Conversion Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/xdb_upgrade_and_conversion_guide_sc75-a4.pdf) for 7.5 this will take your solution and migrate DMS data to xDB, which introduces Mongo.

### Upgrade to Sitecore 8.0 rev. 141212

Following this [xDB Upgrade Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/D1C480A4D4D245E1813FD35D985F8417.ashx) will introduce the initial version of Sitecore 8 and upgrade analytics in xDB to 8.0.

### Upgrade to Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003

Following this [xDB Upgrade Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/ED08679F569742D0B68450E4D1D76AA0.ashx) will bring your Sitecore solution to version 8.1, which has a number of changes related to how analytics are stored.

### Upgrade to Sitecore 9 rev. 171002

Following the [Sitecore Experience Platform Upgrade Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/01B4871056434A52AC69C4ECC29F7834.ashx) will upgrade your solution from 8.1 Initial to Sitecore 9 Initial.

### Use the xDB Data Migration Tool

Once your solution is on Sitecore 9, you can use the [xDB Data Migration Tool](https://doc.sitecore.net/xDB%20Data%20Migration%20Tool/%7E/media/E3447C27EA474799AF0C1CAEF59DBE32.ashx) to migrate your 8.1 xDB Data to Sitecore 9.

This will help you get your analytics from DMS to Sitecore XP 9.  I would offer a note of caution regarding expectations, the data might not display the same.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks Pete
I will try this and let you know.

Can it be possible directly use Express migration tool from 7.2 to 9?

Comment: Just be very diligent in following the guides exactly.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this would even work, or if the data would even make sense. The analytics data model from DMS in 7.2 is nothing like what xDB is now in 9.0. Even if you could somehow run tools to go through versions, I'm not sure you would be able to get value out of the resulting process.

The xDB data migration tool for 9.0 is intended for 8.x where there is a known xDB data model.

There is a tool available to upgrade DMS data to xDB format in 7.5:

https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/Update/7_5_rev_141003.aspx

From there you could upgrade to 8.0 xDB and then try to use the 9.0 migration tool to jump to 9.0 xDB. However, I have no confidence this process would actually work.